# value of textarea : problem in firefox

Tags: jquery

I have written a very simple script with jQuery, but it does not work in Firefox:

```
<a href="" class="po">any text</a>
<form>
    <input type="text" class="infobox" />
    <br />
    <textarea class="me"></textarea>
    <input type="submit"   value="click"  class="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
var vl = $('.po').text();
$('.po').click(function(){
    $('.me').val(vl);
});
```

Why does this script not work in Firefox?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you're not giving any details of what is not working; whether any error messages come up; and which browsers it *does* work in (as opposed to Firefox).

Comment: with click, text area has not any value. Peter Ajtai's answer is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".po")` is a link, so you should use **[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)** or `return false` so you don't navigate away from the page when you click it.

Also make sure you are using `script` tags

```
<a href="" class="po">any text</a>
<form>
<input type="text" class="infobox"/>
<br />
<textarea class="me"></textarea>
<input type="submit"   value="click"  class="submit"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var vl = $('.po').text();
$('.po').click(function(event){
    $('.me').val(vl);
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

### **[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tg7sb/)**

Or, you can put the JS in the head like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {                                                   \\ <== doc ready
    var vl = $('.po').text();
    $('.po').click(function(event){
        $('.me').val(vl);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" class="po">any text</a>
<form>
<input type="text" class="infobox"/>
<br />
<textarea class="me"></textarea>
<input type="submit"   value="click"  class="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### **[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubYZc/)**

Comment: your answer solved my prolem but I cant check this in 9 minutes!Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine, try putting it in ready handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var vl = $('.po').text();
  $('.po').click(function(){
      $('.me').val(vl);
      return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The `return false` that you added in is also essential. Without it, the text gets added, but then the page refreshes, so the original code in the OP isn't really functional in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: True and that explains the very existence of it there :)